# Unmovable struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-constructor

Consider this code with an assumption that the `int state` marks that a struct has some state and that this state is of any complexity:

```
struct Object
{
private:
    int state = 0;

public:
    Object( Object&& other ):
      state( std::move( other.state ) )
    {}
};

struct ReferencingObject
{
private:
    Object& object;
    int     state = 0;

public:
    ReferencingObject( Object& object ):
      object( object )
    {}

    ReferencingObject( ReferencingObject&& other ):
      object( other.object ),
      state( std::move( other.state ) )
    {}
};

struct CannotMove
{
    Object              object;
    ReferencingObject   ref;

    CannotMove():
      object(),
      ref( object )
    {}

    CannotMove( CannotMove&& other ):
      object( std::move( other.object ) ),
      ref( std::move( other.ref ) )
    {}
};
```

1) Focusing on the `CannotMove( CannotMove&& )` move constructor, I'd argue that my current implementation is faulty, because moving the `ReferencingObject` instance keeps reference to a now undefined instance of `Object`, since it was already moved. However, since `ReferencingObject` struct contains a state of its own, my conclusion is that there does not exist a correct move constructor for `CannotMove`. Is my conclusion correct?

2) Let's now assume my conclusion from 1) is correct and that the `CannotMove` is a fairly complex template class. Complex enough that the only reasonable way of obtaining instances (from the user's point of view) is through the use of `auto`, such as:

```
auto cannotMoveInstance = createCannotMove();
```

The `createCannotMove()` function could be written in a way that would allow the compiler to perform copy elision and work around the problem from 1) in this particular case entirely. However, to prevent users of the code from accidentally moving an instance of `CannotMove`, the move constructor should be marked as deleted. This would, however, prevent the compiler from using a copy elision. Am I forced to drop the usage of `auto` and create my instances directly through

```
CannotMove  instance;
```

?

**Edit 1**: data members of `Object` and `ReferencingObject` made private to better reflect typical OOP programming.

Comment: There's no point in `std::move()`'ing an `int`.

Comment: "there does not exist a correct move constructor for CannotMove. Is my conclusion correct?" How can anyone answer that if you don't explain what this class is supposed to do?

Comment: @T.C.: I know, hence the first sentence in my question

Comment: @DDrmmr: The class is supposed to do exactly what is written in the code above. Given the structs above, can you write a well-formed move constructor for `CannotMove`?

Comment: "The class is supposed to do exactly what is written in the code above" means that the class is by definition correct because you say that it does exactly what it is supposed to do. The question "Is it correct?" makes no sense because you already said that it is.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I would expect, after moving an instance of `CannotMove`, to get a new instace working with which would not lead to an undefined behavior. But given my implementation of the move constructor of `CannotMove`, this would be clearly not the case, since `ref` would be holding reference to an undefined instance of `Object`. Maybe "correct" is not the proper word, but I could not think of a better one.

Comment: You need to specify what object it should be a reference to. We asked what the class is supposed to do, and you said it does what it does, which isn't helpful.

Comment: Your code for `ReferencingObject` already doesn't make sense. UB or not, this looks like a horrible design. It would be more fruitful if you explained at a high level (no code) what you want to achieve, so people can suggest good design alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class invariant appears to be *the reference in `ref` always refers to my own `object`*.

To maintain this invariant, the proper way to write the move constructor of `CannotMove` is to move the `Object` and then construct the `ReferencingObject` yourself to refer to your own object. First give  `ReferencingObject` a constructor that moves from the state of a `ReferencingObject &&` but sets the reference to a different `Object`.

```
ReferencingObject( ReferencingObject&& other, Object & obj ):
  object( obj ),
  state( std::move( other.state ) )
{}
```

then:

```
CannotMove( CannotMove&& other ):
  object( std::move( other.object ) ),
  ref( std::move(other.ref), object )
{ }
```

---

If you insist on having the code as written, then no, there's no logically correct way to write a constructor of `CannotMove` because your `ReferencingObject` exposes no interface to move the state but without copying the reference. There are ways to work around this by only altering `CannotMove`'s definition (e.g., storing a smart pointer to `Object` instead of an `Object` directly), but since you don't want to change anything else, then no, it can't be done.

If you delete the move constructor, then `CannotMove` can't be returned and must be constructed directly.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect typical OOP programming style, where data members are private

Comment: Yes, that would work, but you have modified the question by changing the behavior of `ReferencingObject`

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky Well, if you don't change it, then it's a problem with your design - if you want to maintain self-references, then you can't just "copy" references over.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I'm not asking how to change the code to make `CannotMove` struct movable. I'm querying, with the given code, is `CannotMove` a movable struct?